# Multiple "main" targets in a single ESP-IDF project

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I am using ESP-IDF to program an ESP32 chip. In the standard project layout there is one "main" directory containing the "app_main" function, and then a series of components in the "components" directory. I would like to have more than one main target in my project. Is this possible?

Ideally I would organize code like this:

```
my_project/
    main_abc/
        main_abc.c
        ...
    
    main_xyz/
        main_xyz.c
        ...
    
    components/
        my_led_driver/
            ...
        my_network_protocol/
            ...
        my_signal_processor/
            ...
```

and build with `idf.py build main_abc` or  `idf.py build main_xyz`. If this exact setup is not possible then is there a way to do something that satisfies the below motivation?

The reason I want this is that I have a few different programs that all utilize the same set of components but get loaded onto different devices at different times. Because they all share the same components, I want to put them in the same project dir.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking to do something similar.

Comment: @Adam I have not found a solution but I would still very much like to.